# create an array based on two table id's in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have two tables. one is 'demo' and other is 'like'.

I am converting array of values into json format using json_encode.

Demo has :

```
[{ 'id': 1, 'like_id': 2, 'name': 'hero' }, { 'id': 2, 'like_id': 1, 'name': 'villain' }]
```

Like has :

```
[{ 'id': 1, 'movie'': 'castle' }, {'id': 2, 'movie' : 'superman' }]
```

I want to create a new json data as follows:

```
[{ 'id': 1, 'like_id': [{'id': 2, 'movie' : 'superman'}], 'name': 'hero'},
 { 'id': 2, 'like_id': [{'id': 1, 'movie': 'castle'}], 'name': 'villain'}]
```

After searching for a while, I think i might need recursive function. But I am not sure how i can write in this scenario.

This is what i tried :

```
$pages = array();

$demo = Object('demo');
$like = Object('like');

foreach ($demo as $d) {
    foreach ($like as $l) {
        $response = array(
           'id' => $d['id'],
           'like_id' => array(
                 'id' => $l['id'],
                 'movie' => $l['movie']
           ),
           'name' => $d['name']
        );
        array_push($pages, $response);
     }
  }
$res = json_encode($pages);
echo $res;
```

Comment: You don't need recursion. Just nested `foreach` loops.

Comment: Why do you need an array in `like_id` in the result? There's only one ID number in `Demo`, so it should just be replaced with the object from `Like`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried nested foreach. But it multiples more number of times and print the result.

Comment: Show what you tried. How else can we help you understand your error?

Comment: Why would it print the result? You're just using the loop to create a new array, and you call `json_encode` after it's done.

Comment: if those are json strings, they are invalid

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest May I know why its invalid ?

Comment: quotes missed for property names. It can't be parsed correctly

Comment: JSON only uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not checking whether the `id` in `$like` matches the `like_id` in `$demo`, so you're producing all the combinations.

```
foreach ($demo as $d) {
    foreach ($like as $l) {
        if ($d['like_id'] == $l['id']) {
            $response = $d;
            $response['like_id'] = array(array('id' => $l['id'],
                                               'movie' => $l['movie'])
                                         );
            array_push($pages, $response);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/aCa4ik)

Comment: $response = $d; doesnt seems to work. But, when I tried adding as $response = array ( 'id' => 1, name => 'hero' );. This repeats to all possible combinations again. if i try as above, $response['like_id'] will not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I was missing a close brace, so it wouldn't run at all. I guess you added it at the wrong place. I also forgot to put the `like_id` object in an extra level of array (I still don't understand why you have that). I corrected both of these, and now the code works, see the ideone.com demo.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `json_decode` and `str_replace`(to prepare for proper decoding) functions:

```
$demo = "[{ 'id': 1, 'like_id' : 2, 'name': 'hero' }, { 'id': 2, 'like_id': 1, 'name': 'villain' }]";
$likes = "[{ 'id': 1, 'movie': 'castle' }, {'id': 2, 'movie' : 'superman' }]";

$demo_objects = json_decode(str_replace("'",'"',$demo));
$like_objects = json_decode(str_replace("'",'"',$likes));
foreach ($demo_objects as $o) {
    foreach ($like_objects as $l) {
        if ($l->id == $o->like_id) $o->like_id = [$l];
    }

}

print_r(json_encode($demo_objects));
```

The output:

```
[
  {"id":1,"like_id":[{"id":2,"movie":"superman"}],"name":"hero"},
  {"id":2,"like_id":[{"id":1,"movie":"castle"}],"name":"villain"}
]
```